# Starting website on Google chrome in popup window via Batch file

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, popup

I was trying to create a easy batch file to open grooveshark playlist in Google Chrome, but I am unhappy with the fact that playlist opens in new tab — not in popup.

I tried a lot of ways, but couldn't find if there is even a possibility to open new popup window in Chrome via batch file.

Also I was thinking about creating this in .exe in something like Visual Basic, but I am beginner there so I have no idea how should I do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*grooveshark.cmd*

```
@echo off
start "Chrome" chrome --new-window www.grooveshark.com
```

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 
Although I was looking for the classic window without tabs in pop-up,
I am really very happy with this, because I couldn't find this chromium switches and this is pretty enough for me. Thank you sir.